# Branch-misses profiling in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, profiling, visual-studio-2022

On Linux, I have `perf` for profiling branch misses. Is there something similar in `VS 2022`?

Comment: Does it have to be Visual Studio?  It seems that [VTune](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/vtune-profiler.html#gs.44f416) can do it, and I believe that it is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: The equivalent to perf is xperf from the Windows Performance Toolkit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/wpt/ (I don't think there's any integration with Visual Studio though)